# Grails/Hibernate: DuplicateKeyException and NonUniqueObjectException

Tags: java, hibernate, grails

I have a couple of methods that retreive data using GORM and updates and saves. The following errors are thrown.

```
2017-02-14 01:39:02,316 [ERROR ]    A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [com.example.Job#3365090]; nested exception is org.hibern$
org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [com.example.Job#3365090]; nested exception is org.hibernate.Non$
        at com.example.job.JobDaoService.$tt__persistJob(JobDaoService.groovy:88)
        at com.example.job.JobDaoService.$tt__changeJobStatusByJob(JobDaoService.groovy:225)

...
Caused by: org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [com.example.Job#3365090]
        ... 23 more
```

My methods are:
(1)

```
Job persistJob(Job job) throws JobException {
    job.save(flush: true)

    if (job.hasErrors()) {
        throw new JobException("Error (ID: ${job?.id}). Details: ${job.errors}", JOB_CANNOT_BE_CREATED_EXCEPTION)
    }
    return job
}
```

(2)

```
@Synchronized
Job changeStatusByJob(Job job, JobStatus jobStatus) {
    job.refresh()
    job.status = jobStatus

    if (persistJob(job)) {
        log.info("The status is changed.")
    }
    return job
}
```

(3)

```
 @Transactional
 Job getPendingJob() throws JobException {
     return Job.findByStatusAndCreatedLessThanEquals(READY, new Date(), [sort: "type"])
 }
```

I added `@Transactional`, `job.attach()`, `job.refresh()` and nothing worked.

Comment: How does Job look like? Any bi-directional relations? And are these eagerly fetched?

Comment: Yes It has bidirectional relationship and eagerly fetched data but that is not updated before persisting the job. I just read the values of the relationship table.

Comment: Well. If there is such a relation, it is most likely the cause of Non-Unique object exception, since the object is loaded twice in the session...

Comment: Try - just for fun - to remove the "fetch: eager" - and make a getter for the relation on job. And use the getter where u need the relation. Point is, when making `Job.findByStatus ...` make sure only one Job instance is loaded into the session. That is, you cant travese from job -> jobstatus -> job (if that is ur relation) :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to merge your job instance before saving it. Merge() takes the instance passed and merges it with any object of the same id associated with the session.